# JQuery Selectors: Selecting the submit button but not the close button

Tags: jquery, button, jquery-selectors

javascript:

```
<script>
$('#submit').click(function () {
$("p").show("slow");
});
</script>
```

attempt two:

```
<script>
$("input[type='submit']").click(function () {
$("p").show("slow");
});
</script>
```

html:

```
<form>
username:<br>
<input type="text" name="un"><br>
password:<br>
<input type="password" name="pw"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="pw">
remember me<br>
<p><a href="recover.php">recover password</a></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit"></p>
<p style="display: none; color:cc0000">Authentication failed.</p>
<p><button onclick="window.top.hidePopWin()">Close</button></p>
</form>
```

Am I messing up my syntax on the selectors here? The submit button doesn't seem to display the hidden message using either method..

Comment: What dpes "doesn't work" mean? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: It should show the "Authentication failed" text, or whatever text is hidden within <p> tags.

Comment: missing `.preventDefault()` and a `<button />` without a `type`-attribute will act as a `submit`-button

Comment: I hope you put the script *after* the elements. Otherwise jQuery cannot find them. If you didn't, then you should [this introduction to jQuery](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/) to learn how to set it up properly.

Comment: color:cc0000, missing a `#`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prevent submitting of the form by adding `return false;` to the end of your click function, as well as the end of your onclick button function since it also behaves as a submit button the way you set it up.

So, something like this:

```
<script>
$('#submit').click(function () {
    $("p").show("slow");
    return false;
});
</script>
```

See it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/w7DWV/).

Comment: +1 I just focused on markup problems, you suggested the important thing :)

Comment: Yeah, the question wasn't really clear so we both had to guess. :) Also, it's not a good practice to copy other's answers (both you and that other guy), even parts of them...